# Как запустить несколько графических приложений/дисплеев на VPS?

Tags: linux, консоль, vps

возможно на одном VPS сервере запустить несколько виртуальных графических дисплеев? Т.е. мне необходимо запустить несколько независимых экземпляров gui-приложения и отслеживать их, из консоли на одном vps. Как это реализовать?
Я пытаюсь запустить код, командой xvfb-run python3 main.py, мне выдает ошибку

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'google-chrome --proxy-server=95.136.76.230:113': 'google-chrome --proxy-server=95.136.76.230:113'

в коде chrome_path = 'google-chrome --proxy-server=95.136.76.230:113

Comment: видимо, что-то мешает вам просто взять и запустить «несколько независимых экземпляров gui-приложения и отслеживать их, из консоли на одном vps». изложите это прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: что, я как-то не понятно изложил??? ok, как запустить из консоли 3 браузера chrome, чтобы на одном у меня был открыт stackoverflow, на втором yandex, на третьем еще что-то...

Comment: вот, уже есть подробности. лучше их было изложить в тексте самого вопроса. // в частном случае с программой chrome/chromium для запуска двух несвязанных наборов процессов можно, к примеру, использовать опцию `--user-data-dir`

Comment: не Headless Chrome ли вы ищете на самом деле?

Comment: может автор вопроса ищет Xvfb, Xnest или Xephyr

Comment: @KoVadim Возможно Xvfb. По крайней мере я пытался запустить xvfb-run python3 main.py, мне выдает ошибку FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'google-chrome --proxy-server=95.136.76.230:113': 'google-chrome --proxy-server=95.136.76.230:113' в main путь такой chrome_path = 'google-chrome --proxy-server=95.136.76.230:113'

Comment: а если просто скрипт запустить, без Xvfb, то оно запускается?

Comment: @KoVadim как же он запуститься из консоли, если google-chrome подразумевает графический рабочий стол (или я чего-то не понимаю?). Нет, не запускается (keyError: 'DISPLAY')

Comment: запустите на своей машине. Но если что, то можно запустить вот так `Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x8 & export DISPLAY=":99" && python3 main.py` - то есть, запускаем Xvfb на определенном экране, экспортим эту переменную и далее запускаем скрипт.

Comment: Зачем вы запихнули аргументы в параметр, который должен содержать только путь к исполняемому файлу хрома? Естественно оно запускаться не будет

Comment: @andreymal а как запустить с параметрами из командной строки? в частности с указанием прокси?

Comment: А это уже показывайте свой python-скрипт. Это ошибка в вашем скрипте, которая не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения к запуску графики